# Export DXF ArcMap to read in AutoCAD (No attributes)

Tags: arcmap, fields-attributes, autocad, cad

Could anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

I have a shapefile in ArcMap which I have exported to a DXF.

When I import it back into ArcMap I can see it has attributes.

However when I open this in AutoCAD it does not retain the attributes.

Does anyone know how I can export a shapefile to a DXF in ArcMap and retain the attributes for AutoCAD?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the different ways to get the attributes of a shapefile into CAD:

1. Adding the shapefile directly into CAD without exporting: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/MAP3D-Learn/files/GUID-56DC6613-02F1-425A-AD7A-B5EAD35FDE1C-htm.html
2. Block attributes method: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/cad/exporting-attributes-to-autocad-block-attributes.htm

   [**How To: Create AutoCAD BLOCKS with attributes from ArcGIS point features**](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000007547)
3. Annotation method: http://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000008383